# How can you scroll through numpy array images in PyQt5?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5

How can you scroll through Numpy array images in PyQt5? This is the shape of my input images array:

```
X = [512, 512, 100]
```

I tried using the onscroll method which uses mouse scroll event and we can mpl_connect it on the canvas (Matplotlib). This seems to work fine but when I put this canvas on PyQt5 canvas, the scrolling stops. Is there any way I can implement this in PyQt5?

I have tried to keep this question simple because I want a generic answer, but if someone is interested, I am ready to share the (non-working) code.

Comment: Why not to use `QLabel`s to represent images?

Comment: There is no reason `mpl_connect` wouldn't work in PyQt5 canvas, since the canvas you get when using `plt.show()` in the Qt5Agg backend is the same canvas. This being said, as long as there is no [mcve], this question is pretty useless.